# Clear all records from combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

Hello i am have combobox and button. When combobox is empty - button is disabled, when combobox have records - button is enabled. If i am reload form where placed combobox and button,  how to do combobox totally empty - clear all records (that button is disable). That my combobox

```
                {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                width: 350,
                store: 'Books',
                queryMode: 'local',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<div class="x-boundlist-item">' + Text + '</div>',
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),
                displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                        Text ,
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),
                valueField: 'id',
                name: 'Books',
                disable:'false',
                listeners: {
                     select: function(combo) {
                        if (this.getValue() === null) {
                            Ext.getCmp('books_all').setDisabled(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            Ext.getCmp('books_all').setDisabled(false);
                        }

                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: do you want to empty the store? or do you want to set the text inside the combobox to ""? I don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: hello, thanks. I am want  to empty the store!

Comment: you mean this: `combo.getStore().removeAll()` ?

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer to make this more clear for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove all entries from a combobox you need to empty the underlying store:

```
combo.getStore().removeAll()
```